# What syntax is best to use for an if statement with one piece of functionality inside?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, coding-style

For example:

```
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  foo();
}
```

or

```
e.keyCode === 13 ? foo() : null;
```

I understand that this only applies to if statements with a single piece of functionality as a result, but for readability and to lessen the lines of code I would think the second example would make more sense. This is a curiosity I've always had and just wondering if there are any reasons to choose one style over the other. Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: The second is less readable. If number of lines is your concern, do `if (e.keyCode === 13) foo();` - also less readable. I wouldn't make fewer lines a primary goal, if the aim is readability; let your minifier reduce the line count ;)

Comment: "*What's the best syntax for an `if` statement?*" - an `if` statement!

Comment: @CaiusJard that's a good point. I always have the "Less is more" thought, and finding the balance between the "Less is more" mentality and readability is a struggle sometimes.

Comment: Sometimes I expand conditional operators to if because I find them more readable, particularly in the case of `a === b ? (c === d ? e : f) : (g === h ? i : j)` - this is only just readable now - chuck a bunch of variable names,  a few more && and + concatenations in there and it's sunk!

Answer (score 1):

You missed the third approach by using a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) operator, like

```
e.keyCode === 13 && foo()
```

This main result of this expression is either `false` or the result of the call of `foo`.

If the result is never used and the compiler should evaluate the expression you may use the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) with the expression.

```
void e.keyCode === 13 && foo();
```

This forces the expression to evaluate and returns `undefined`.

---

If you need not to use the result of the expression,

```
if (e.keyCode === 13) foo();
```

is the most short and understandable statement.